# which is more reliable for passing empty argument, null or undefined? (while expecting a function)

Tags: javascript, function, null, parameter-passing, undefined

> If we’re interested only in errors, then we can use null as the first
> argument: .then(null, errorHandlingFunction). Or we can use
> .catch(errorHandlingFunction), which is exactly the same:

[from javascript.info](https://javascript.info/promise-basics#then)

---

when we want to pass first argument as empty, is there any difference between `null` and `undefined`? I think `undefined` is more convenient because when we call a function without any argument then all arguments will be `undefined`. So what is the best and why?

Thanks

edit:
for example

```
.then(null, errorHandlingFunction)
//or
.then(undefined, errorHandlingFunction)
```

But I asked general purpose not only for `.then()`

edit 2: it is very funny. Stack Overflow admins marked this question as a "opinion based". So what can I do? I just want opinions of other people with reliable reasons for general usage not specific code snippet.

Comment: The link you provided is about using Promises. Is your question related about Promises as well? Could you show an example of a scenario where you would encounter this dilemma?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I add extra information. I just want to know the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.then`, it doesn't matter. If the first argument is not callable, then no matter what its value, it will be completely ignored. See the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen):

> 3. If IsCallable(onFulfilled) is false, then

> a. Let onFulfilledJobCallback be empty.

So you could just as well do `.then(123, errorHandlingFunction)`.

But if you aren't going to pass an `onFulfilled` callback as the first argument at all, using `.then` doesn't make sense - you should use `.catch` instead:

```
.catch(errorHandlingFunction)
```

which is exactly equivalent to

```
.then(somethingNotCallable, errorHandlingFunction)
```

except that it's more semantically correct and easier to read.

> But I asked general purpose not only for `.then()`

It's up to you; you can specify the logic you want, and users of the function will have to adhere to it.

One thing to keep in mind is that if `undefined` is used as an argument, default arguments can be used, but if `null` is passed, default arguments will not be used:

```js
const fn = (someArg = 5) => {
  console.log(someArg);
};

fn(null);
fn(undefined);
```

Comment: thank you. I understand but this situation is just an example. I want to know which one is good and acceptable for general usage for sending empty argument?

Comment: Both work just fine. I would be very suspicious of code that depended on checking the distinction between an error argument being `null` or `undefined`. The difference should not matter to anyone, I'd hope.

Comment: So when we call third party function "null" can broke the "default argument" mechanism so using "undefined" is better in general

Comment: Only if the other function has the ability to assign a default argument - it may or it may not.